# Copy part of two-dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, copy

So I have a matrix M1 that I build at the beginning of my method each method call (this is all done in a non-static environment). The issue is that, depending on an integer index, say **n** I want the matrix M2 (in method call #2 for example) to contain rows 1, 2... **n** of M1 (the number of rows that I need for M changes each method call, but the number of columns persist).

My method in pseudocode;

```
int myMethod(numRows, numColumns, n) {

  Initialize M as matrix with dimensions(numRows, numColumns)
  if (n > 0) {
    **copy rows 1,2...,n from previous M matrix**
  }
  **do stuff with M**
  return M[numRows][numColumns];
```

What is a smart way to accomplish this? I hope it's clear what I'm asking for. Something worth noting is that **Mi** can be 'taller' or 'shorter' (it's always exactly as 'wide') as **Mj** for i > j

Comment: you can also make use of a general method and use -deep-copy technology http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564832/how-do-i-do-a-deep-copy-of-a-2d-array-in-java or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64036/how-do-you-make-a-deep-copy-of-an-object-in-java

Comment: Right, thank you! How would you go about keeping the old M between runs? Keep it as an attribute in my class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe return the array and pass the array as a parameter.

```
int[][] mymethod(int[][]oldArray, int noOfRows){
 int[][] newArr;
 if(noOfRows > 0){
  //here copy from oldArray to new;
  //sorry this is where I can't remember, you will have
  //to do something to get column size maybe oldArray[0].length()
  // but that may not work if each row has different length.
  newArr = new int[noOfRows][];
  for(int i=0; i < noOfRows; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < noOfRows; j++){
     newArr[i][j] = oldArray[i][j];
    }
  }
 }
return newArr;
}
```

after this just call the method.
    int [][] a = mymethod(dArray,5);
    int [][] b = mymethod(a, 2);

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that's what I got since I asked aswell - although it feels like there should be some more time-efficient way to do this maybe it has to do! Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: No problem. I am also looking for more efficient ways of doing things. But first have it done in the most easy way you can have it done then refactor it with a more elegant and efficient way. I will keep looking back to this post to see if we can get a better solution. Anyways, cheers!

Comment: @NyfikenGul you may want to see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5617016/how-do-i-copy-a-2-dimensional-array-in-java?rq=1. it has something very interesting regarding using System.Arraycopy. that way you only need to iterate the rows and then use that method. I don't know if that more efficient but it is less code.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into that and let you know how it goes!

Comment: Actually it was even worse time-wise, iterating over the rows and columns actually worked quicker. Strange.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11304459/how-to-use-multi-dimensional-vector-in-java) dimensional [vector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html), and then perhaps the [clone()](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0140__Collections/CopyingandCloningVectors.htm) method. The awesome thing about vector is that it can grow and shrink as you need it to.

Comment: Thank you! Feels like it should be able to be done with arrays though (the rest of my program uses arrays so)

Comment: No worries! It does look like [arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) have a .copyOf(T[] original_arr, int newlength)  -Disclaimer, I've never used the method, but it looks pretty handy.